# identify cases when a value of a column appeared in that same column while the value of another column changed

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with two columns, one is composed by card IDs and the other is the number of the week (an integer). Each use of the card generates a row in the dataframe with that card ID and the number of the week in which it was used. So for a particular week number y have multiple rows with different card IDs and also the same card ID can be repeated multiple times for the same number of the week. What I want to di is to determine how many NEW cards are used each week compared to the previos week, the previous two weeks and so on.

I mean, I want to add a column to the dataframe with the name for example "used_last_week" that adopts a 1 if that card ID was used in the last week and a 0 if not. Then add another column to the dataframe that adopts a 1 if that card ID was used in the previous week of last week and a 0 if not. And so on untill 4 weeks prior.

How can I do this ? I thought of a foor and while loop, but I couldn´t pull it out.

Thank you verymuch.

PD: the card ID variable and the number of the week variable are both numeric.

What I have now is this:

```
card_id       num_week
123234            1
124531            1
345124            1
451433            1
512453            2
123234            2
124531            2
235467            2
145246            3
134353            3
512453            3
123234            3
```

And I want to result in something like this:

```
card_id       num_week    used_week_prior used_2_weeks_priors
123234            1              0                 0
124531            1              0                 0 
345124            1              0                 0 
451433            1              0                 0
512453            2              0                 0
123234            2              1                 0
124531            2              1                 0
235467            2              0                 0 
145246            3              0                 0 
134353            3              0                 0
512453            3              1                 0 
123234            3              1                 1
```

That´s the idea but with columns all the way untill "used_4_weeks_prior"

Comment: Please show us some sample data, desired output, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please share a reproducible example of your data using ``dput`` and edit the output into your question.

Comment: See revised answer.  Trying it in `dplyr` only too, but may be I am missing somewhere, therefore, not working in `dplyr` only.  Do it in `purrr` anyways

Answer (score 0):

For mutating 4 (or more) columns at once, you can adopt the following approach.

```r
df <- read.table(text = 'card_id       num_week
123234            1
124531            1
345124            1
451433            1
512453            2
123234            2
124531            2
235467            2
145246            3
134353            3
512453            3
123234            3', header = T)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  bind_cols(map_dfc(1:4, ~df %>% group_by(card_id) %>%
                      transmute(!!paste0('weeks_prior', .x) := +((row_number() - .x) > 0)
                                           ) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-card_id)
                    ))
#>    card_id num_week weeks_prior1 weeks_prior2 weeks_prior3 weeks_prior4
#> 1   123234        1            0            0            0            0
#> 2   124531        1            0            0            0            0
#> 3   345124        1            0            0            0            0
#> 4   451433        1            0            0            0            0
#> 5   512453        2            0            0            0            0
#> 6   123234        2            1            0            0            0
#> 7   124531        2            1            0            0            0
#> 8   235467        2            0            0            0            0
#> 9   145246        3            0            0            0            0
#> 10  134353        3            0            0            0            0
#> 11  512453        3            1            0            0            0
#> 12  123234        3            1            1            0            0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I tried this and the problem is that it is not agrouping the card_ids. It is just considering if each card_id was used before, not if it was used in a different week. So in the third column for example, it is giving me 1s for card_ids that have been used previously in that same week, and that´s not what I want, I want it to be a 1 only if that card_id has been used in the previous week at least once, I don´t care how many times it was used this week.

Comment: Can you modify your example data, please